# Parallel save error in mongoose post init hook. Can't save() the same doc multiple times in parallel

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, fastify

So here's a problem which i am facing when i am using the post init hook whenever the date changes i update some values in the db. but when i am trying to make a get call the parallel save error comes up, but the values in database get updated and if i try to hit api again it works perfectly fine, so why do i get this parallel save error just once and not again until the date changes again.

```
influencerSchema.post('init', async function (doc) {
  let metaData = influencerModel.metaData();
  let refreshFields = metaData.refreshFields;
  for (let i = 0; i < refreshFields.length; i++) {
    if (new Date(doc.currentMembership[refreshFields[i]].dailyCount.date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0) != new Date().setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)) {
      doc.currentMembership[refreshFields[i]].dailyCount.date = Date.now();
      doc.currentMembership[refreshFields[i]].dailyCount.count = doc.currentMembership[refreshFields[i]].count;
      await doc.save();
    }
  }
});
```

here refresh fields are

```
refreshFields: ['likes', 'messages', 'matches', 'backtrack']
```

any help would be great
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are trying to save the doc multiple times in a init hook in the first place. AFAIK this is not necessary. I would drop the line `await doc.save();` entirely (and make the function non-async). Should be OK if you save the doc later anyway.

The error occurs exactly for the reason the error message is stating: You are trying to save the document muliple times in parallel.

Checkout https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post-async
You are not using the async function schema because you are required to call `next()` when you are done with your async processing.

So either don't save the doc in the hook or use the `next()` callback when done with async stuff.